# posting saml file using php curl and converting C# code to php

Tags: c#, php, curl, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to httpost saml file in php using curl for sso purposes but the xml contents need to be encoded into byte utf8 and then base64(that's the requirements of the company i am posting to) so they gave me this piece c# and they told me to convert it to php
this is what i get to so far with my php curl saml post:

---

```
<?php
$url = "https://my.sandbox.company.com/sso/authenticate.ashx";
$filename = "saml.xml";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$XPost = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
echo urlencode($XPost);
fclose($handle);

$decdata = urlencode($XPost);
$raw = base64_encode($decdata);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $raw);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process
if (empty($result)) {
die(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
} else {
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch); // close cURL handler
if (empty($info['http_code'])) {
die("No HTTP code was returned");
} 
else {
echo "The server responded: \n";
echo $info['http_code'] . " " . $http_codes[$info['http_code']];
}
}

echo "RESULT: $result"; //contains response from server

?>
```

---

The C# code given

```
string responseStr = doc.OuterXml;
byte[] base64EncodedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseStr);
string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(base64EncodedBytes);
```

---

Please let me know if my code is wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Is it running as expected? Are there any problems currently?

Comment: the post to the url is working but it's authenticating properly. it will redirect me to their signup page

Comment: sorry it's not authenticating properly